# How to retrieve column data from ruby object returned from sql query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
 sql = "Select * from clients where id=1"
        records_array = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
       puts(records_array.id)
```

I get an error if even though the query should contain an object with an id

NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for #):

Comment: Why use SQL in this case ? You can simply use `Client.find(1)`

Answer (score 0):

You executing the method `.id` for a hash (the return of  `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)`), Hashes instances don't have this method.
This method will return for you a sql Result, you can access the client attriubutes executing:

```
records_array.first
```

This will return for you a array of attributes of the finded client:

```
[1, 'Client name', 'Client birthday']
```

I strongly recommend you to use a `.find` method from the class `Client` if you using `ActiveRecord`

Comment: No, the returning is a SqlAdapter::Result. Suposing he using mysql, the result will be: `Mysql2::Result:0x00000004be4b60`

Answer (score 0):

Always try to guess what method can help you. When you write `record_arrays.methods` it returns a list of available methods that can help you.  For example, `records_array.column_values(0)` it is going to return all values from the first column, in this case maybe the list of all client ids, another method is `records_array.values`. You can check what method can help you.